# form_rest command showing previously-rendered Collection field

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form with a collection type field, rendered like that:

```
<div id="beneficiosTab" class="opcional">
    Beneficios
    <ul class="beneficios" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(formAtendimento.beneficios.get('prototype')) | e }}">
        {% for beneficio in formAtendimento.beneficios %}
            <li>{{ form_row(beneficio.coTipoBeneficio) }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_row(beneficio.vrValor) }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_row(beneficio.boConcedido) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li><a href="#" id="addBeneficio">Add Beneficio</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
{{ form_rest(formAtendimento) }}
```

The form's entity can have multiple items of the collection, or none.

When the entity has items of the collection, it works fine, but when it has none, the "for" in the twig doesn't happen, and a "Beneficios" div is generated in form_rest.

Any way I can prevent that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest to add a new Beneficios on the Atendimiento entity on your controller if it doesn't have any, that way your form will have a default form to add one from the start and you avoid that problem. Later in the saving controller, if the Beneficios form is empty, just remove it to avoid saving it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the form rendering. I managed to disable the extra form rendering in the form_rest function, by adding this code just after rendering the collection elements:

```
{% do form.uploads.setRendered() %}
```

Where "uploads" is my collection field type. 
This doesn't seem like best practice to me though.

So the whole rendering looks like this:

```
 <div id="uploads" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.uploads.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for upload in form.uploads %}
            {{ form_widget(upload) }}
        {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% do form.uploads.setRendered() %}
```

Answer (score 0):

form_rest generate all unrendered forms. Every input is form in Symnfony2, the same goes with collection type.

You never printed out collection, so Symfony makes it for you.
If you want hide it, and still use form_rest simply print it it to:

```
<div style="display: none" />
```